# How do you calculate the compared populations in cox hazard ratio problems?

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, hazard

Take a look at the following open-access paper

```
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26506242
```

I've tried doing cox regression in both R and SPSS but I cannot get the numbers of populations (No. of events and No. of patients as listed in all tables involving hazard ratios). Does anybody know the meaning of these numbers and how to calculate them using statistical software ?